# Avoiding references

Tags: references

I am currently on my notice period because I accepted offer from another company. I don't want them to call my current company and ask for references (i have no problems if they call to my previous companies).

Could asking not to call to the current one have negative impact for the hiring decision of new company?

Comment: I'm a little confused by this question. If you've already been made an offer, accepted it, and resigned your current position, why would the new employer be checking references _now_? And why is it a problem if they are?

Comment: Yes, they do check for references after the offer is made and accepted by me (the contract is not signed yet).

Comment: The wrong thing here is resigning before the contract has been signed. This can hurt you very badly.

Comment: You current employer already knows you are leaving soon, why do you consider it a problem if the new employer contacts them now?

Comment: @Carson63000 - In the UK the offer is usually subject to references/background checks etc.

Comment: how long were you at your current company?

Comment: [This answer to a very similar question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/61184/2322) is probably what you want here, too. Different question, but I think I could copy/paste that answer here.

Comment: If references are still being checked YOU HAVE NOT RECEIVED A FIRM OFFER.

Comment: @DJClayworth that does seem odd.  Still, it's a bad idea for any employer to contact a current employer.  I've seen managers lie about the employee more than once.  You won't get an accurate appraisal from a current employer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you are based, but from my experience there are 2 different things here:

1. The employer is seeking a reference, this does still happen (in my experience in smaller companies), but usually this happens BEFORE an offer is made.  In this you don't really have an option, the employer will expect good feedback from your current employer, if you are concerned about what they say, you need to get onto this NOW, and pre-empt it, possibly suggesting a different party who can vouch for you.  But beware, the fact your current employer won't will be a red flag to them (unless the outgoing employer is someone they know to be suspect).
2. What is more likely given the position you describe, is employment verification, where they will simply be checking you have the title/role you say and dates.  There is usually a clause in your contract joining that they have the right to withdraw if an anomaly comes up in verification.

In my experience (having worked in enhanced verification areas like police and banks), the second option is probably what is happening, and the likelihood is that you don't really need to avoid it, and if it is the other situation I don't think you really can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is that employers don't ask references from a current employer.  The reason for that is that if you're a bad employee, they'll lie about you to make you someone else's problem, and if you are a good one, they'll lie to keep you or out of revenge.  I have personally witnessed this more than once.

It is also policy at some companies that employees are not allowed to give out any information about current employees.  HR departments know this so they usually skip the current employer, except for details of employment such as start date, end date, and title.

Comment: Companies tend not to lie. End up in courts etc.

Comment: How naïve for you to think so.  Next thing you're going to say is that they don't fire people for having disabilities.

Comment: Surely that retire people on medical grounds.

Comment: Yeah, right.  I've got a bridge in Brooklyn for sale too.  Either you've worked for the most ethical companies in the world, or you haven't seen what's going on around you.  You can keep saying it doesn't happen, but given the choice between believing you and my own eyes, I'll rely on what I've personally witnessed.  Retired on medical grounds.  HA!

Comment: Perhaps living in Europe helps

Comment: Yes, yes, you're so much better than us, I've read your other comments.

Comment: @Ed While correct in theory, it is highly unlikely that the company would land in court over this. Company B is not going to sue Company A for lying, it is just too much trouble over a single candidate, who is usually just another disposable resource. That leaves the candidate himself, who needs solid proof that Company A lied to Company B, which too he is unlikely to get. If Company A/B is required by law to disclose the reference to him, then OP has no reason to ask this question.

Comment: @MaskedMan YEP, I have spoken to people at the Dept of Labor. Nobody at the hiring company is going to get involved because anyone crazy enough to do that would be crazy enough to harass the hiring company.  Nobody at the previous company is going to say boo, because they've just witnessed the company destroy someone and they don't want to be next.  What's legal, and what's done are two thing.

Comment: An employee can easily sue a company if the company gives a very bad reference .This is one reason why many companies have a policy to never give bad references .

Comment: @Autistic.  Can sue, yes, can easily sue, no.  Here's a reference for you that isn't bad until you look at it carefully:  "During Autistics time on the job, he demonstrated the importance of good hiring processes and we had a discussion about hiring another person like Autistic immediately.  He was never caught sleeping on the job and many of his coworkers were willing to comment on his work."